# Can't import file from separate folder

Tags: python

I am currently working on a Python project and am trying to import a file from a separate directory in Python. Everything I do to try and import this file seems to not work. Here is the following directory structure:

```
Algorithms/
    Unsupervised/
        examples/
            -BSAS.ipynb
        -BSAS.py
```

I am trying to import the module BSAS.py in the examples/BSAS.ipynb by doing:

```
from Unsupervised import BSAS
```

PyCharm says this is valid code, but when I then run the program I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Unsupervised'
```

Comment: Try from Algorithms.Unsupervised import BSAS

Comment: @ShishiSonsonCode it gives me: Unresolved reference 'Algorithms'

Comment: `Unresolved reference` does not sound like a Python error.  Where, exactly, does this error come from?

Comment: @JohnGordon its from PyCharm, it underlines it as red and says Unresolved reference, if I try and run it says Module Not Found Error as well

Comment: Did you add any of these folders to `sys.path`?

Comment: @JohnGordon it does work when I add the Algorithms folder as an absolute file path, when I try to do this with a relative filepath it doesn't work. Ideally I would have this as a relative filepath so if anyone downloads this code it would work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve this problem as @JohnGordon suggested was to add the Algorithms folder to the system path using a relative file path:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'./Algorithms')
```